# Custom CSS in wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the Directory+ theme from ait themes on wordpress. I'm very bad at css and have only just started learning the basics.

There is a custom css section built into the theme to overwrite little bits and pieces. I have plenty in there and it's all working perfectly fine. However I'm struggling with changing something.

Why isn't this the correct way to change the colour? Can you please tell me how to write it the correct way and explain why this isn't working.

```
    #elm-search-form-5-main a, #elm-search-form-5-main a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use same color for default and hovered link

Try to do it like this

This css for default link

```
 #elm-search-form-5-main a{
    color: #ffffff;
 }
```

And this css for hovered link

```
 #elm-search-form-5-main a:hover {
    color: #000000;
 }
```

Look at this [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok. Have you tested it in your web-browser developer tools to see if your element `elm-search-form-5-main a`change the color?